# Unable to create Azure Resource Group project in restricted internet

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-group

**Steps to repro:**

1. Install Visual Studio 2019 16.2 with Azure Development
2. Open Visual Studio 2019 in Administrator mode
3. Search for Azure Resource Group project and language C#
4. Click on Next
5. Leave Default name or provide the name
6. Leave the framework to 4.7.2
7. Click on Create

An error occurred sending request message is displayed.

**Troubleshooting steps**

Checked the signed visual studio subscription account and is having valid subscription

Repaired visual studio

Uninstalled and re-installed

Performed fresh installation on a different server

I have raised as problem in developer community and also provided a solution based on the full internet access provided by network team.

Team had closed the ticket as not a bug. Need help on this one.

Has anyone faced similar problem and how did you guys get this fixed in your environment.

Comment: what help do you need? this is working like you said, so what do you want us to do?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Do we really need full internet in order to work with cloud related project templates?

Comment: what do you mean full internet, you need to be able to talk to the cloud provider api, how else do you want to interact with the cloud provider? by thought?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Full internet meaning no restrictions to any website in network. My organisation is having very restricted internet policy. I'm here to take the thought process of many professionals who are working on cloud project and every organisation might having same set of internet restrictions. Taking the opinion from them would be useful in such instances. I'm aware that cloud projects do talk to the publicly exposed cloud api in order to get the latest definition files for projects. Thanks for your time. Visual Studio team has understood my issue and are working on my issue.